# Connecting to PostgreSQL with SSL using OpenSSL s_client

Tags: openssl, postgresql

I am trying to connect to my PostgreSQL server on AWS using SSL from the OpenSSL `s_client` on XP. I can connect to a third party using this `s_client`. On both the server and XP, I am using openssl version 0.9.8.k.

When I try to connect to my server, I get the result:

`CONNECTED(00000003)
2036:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188
:`

In the Postgres log, I see the entry:

`2009-10-30 13:58:08 UTC LOG:  invalid length of startup packet`

I'd appreciate any suggestions about where to look to get this working.  Maybe there is a public AWS image I can look at on which PostgreSQL is known to work?

Answer (score 26):

You didn't specify *why* you wanted to use *s_client*.

If it is to **interact** with the database, any decent client will do. `psql` can be called with the `sslmode=require` option. See `man psql`.

If it is to **check the SSL certificate** (which is why I came across your question), <del>it still doesn't work with *s_client* as Magnus pointed out 7 years ago.</del> you can now do it with `openssl s_client` if you have a version >= 1.1.1, as pointed out in the answer of Adam Batkin. Use `openssl version` to check, or just directly try this command to see if it works.

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -starttls postgres -connect EXAMPLE.COM:5432 -showcerts
```

If you have an older version which doesn't support postgres, this python script can also retrieve the SSL certificate: https://github.com/thusoy/postgres-mitm/blob/master/postgres_get_server_cert.py

For example to check certificate dates:

```
postgres_get_server_cert.py example.com:5432 | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

Comment: Those on a recent version of macOS will need to use one installed with homebrew; the version of `openssl` that comes installed doesn't support the `postgres` option

Answer (score 10):

It looks like OpenSSL's `s_client` tool added Postgres support using the `-starttls` in 1.1.1, so you can now use the full power of OpenSSL's command line tools without additional helper scripts:

```
> openssl s_client -starttls postgres -connect my.postgres.host:5432 # etc...
```

References:

- [Git commit](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/b2e54eb834e2d5a79d03f12a818d68f82c0e3d13)
- [s_client manpage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/s_client.html)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to check an AWS RDS Postgres instance from an EC2 after forcing ssl.

Comment: Protocol 'postgres' isn't available on my MacOS. openssl version
LibreSSL 2.8.3. I had to fire up a vagrant box (oracle-linux) and go with OpenSSL. openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021. That worked!

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use *s_client*. PostgreSQL does protocol negotiation *before* SSL is started (to figure out if it should do SSL or not, since they both run on the same port). You need to use a proper PostgreSQL client (such as *psql* or *pgadmin*, for example), not *s_client*.

Comment: This helped me understand why it wasn't working. Things have changed since this answer, and the next question explains how to do it with s_client now.